# How to remove the small time picker at the bottom of the plotly chart?

Tags: python, plotly

how can I remove the bottom area of the chart?
Thanks

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a copy of the official ploty-website about [Candlestick-Plots](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) from the chapter "Candlestick without Rangeslider".

The important change is this additional line `fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'], high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'], close=df['AAPL.Close'])
                     ])

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```